# Automatically calculated sum is wrong

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have a problem in Power BI that I don't understand.

I have a table Y2_Tarif that contains values like this:

```
stylecode prix code_tarif
000453-ET1 38,7 T40
000453-ET2 38,7 T40
00091-ET1 34,1 T40
```

I have a first formula which is :

```
Sum_Price:=CALCULATE(sum(Y2_Tarif[prix]))
```

And a second one which is:

```
Valo_T40_TY:=([Sum_Price])*(Y2_Sales[TY_Units]).
```

TY_Units is the number of units sold.

Opening my model in Excel or Power BI directly I get this :

[image]

The formula makes me Units * price.
But in the automatically calculated sum I find a huge number which is not the real sum.

For example this with Excel :

[image]

There should be a sum of 321 639.85€ but I get 46 256 976.99€. Same thing in Power BI:

[image]

I don't have many numbers, the sum doesn't add up to 8 108 209.20€. All the other sums are correct, like the Units sum but not this one.

I don't understand how to change this automatically calculated sum. And where can this large value come from? I have looked at my relationships between the tables and they look good.

Thanks for your help

Update:

[image]

Comment: What is the total sum of the `units`, and the total sum of the `prix`, and what do you get if you multiply those two together?

Comment: In Power BI the sum of the price is also wrong. Could this be because I am taking the column from the table directly without a calculated column? I added a screenshot, I find 89 101.20 in price whereas it is not that but multiplied by 91 it makes well 8 108 209.20€. In Excel there is no sum for price as it is a line and not a Value.

Comment: It can also come from the type of column? Currency, decimal number etc?

Comment: I would suggest you create a calculated column, not a measure, that multiplies the units by the price. Then simply sum those up in your measure.

Comment: it doesn't work... I made a calculated column TY=Y2_Tarif[prix]*Y2_Sales[TY_Units] and a measure Valo_T40_TY_2:=CALCULATE(sum(Y2_Tarif[TY])) but when I add the two fields in my table to check I have completely inconsistent values

Comment: I don't understand that formula. It should be in the Sales table (I assume) and look something like: `TY = RELATED(Tarif[Prix])*[Units]`

Comment: This does not work... "prix" is a column in the Y2_Tarif table and "TY_Units" is a measure in the Y2_Sales table

Comment: What's the formula for the measure? Surely you can use whatever column it is derived from?

Comment: First, I have a formula "
Sum_Prix:=CALCULATE(sum(Y2_Tarif[prix]))" which makes the sum of the "price" column and then I make the price*units with this formula : Valo_T40_TY:=([Sum_Price])*(Y2_Sales[TY_Units]) .And it is this formula Valo_T40_TY which has a bad total

Comment: You said `TY_Units` is a measure. What is the formula for that measure?

Comment: The formula is : TY_Units:=CALCULATE(sum(Y2_Sales[quantity]))

Comment: Then use `TY = RELATED(Tarif[Prix])*[Quantity]` in the calculated column formula in the Sales table.

Comment: it works!!! Thank you very much for your time and your explanations

Comment: Glad we got there in the end. :)